# Sum Nullable Decimal to percentage with a Linq Lambda Function

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

### Update..

I was asking for that...

I have a FOR statement. The FOR statement itnerates through the reportList. The reportList object is a list type set to a specific view in the database.

The FOR loops through the reportList and creates a report. At the end of the report I must output a percentage from a nullable decimal value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < reportList.Count() - 1; i++)
{

   print report totals...
   lastly print percentage...
   htw.Write(reportList.Where(x => x.Name == reportList[i].Name && x == reportList[i].Value).Select(a => a.RequiredValue == null ? 0 : a.RequiredValue).Sum(a => a.Value * 100));
   }
```

### Update After Comments

After comments I have replaced the null logic to...

```
htw.Write(reportList.Where(x => x.Name == reportList[i].Name && x == reportList[i].Value).Select(a => a.RequiredValue ?? 0 : a.RequiredValue).Sum(a => a.Value * 100));
```

With this said, my question is, is this the best way to output a percentage using Linq and Lambda? Is there an operator I am not using? Is the Sum needed? I just need to convert a decimal to a percentage and take in account for nulls.

Comment: Don't do `FirstOrDefault()` on your list.  That is making only do the `Sum` on that first element in the list.

Comment: You can also shorten this with the [null-coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator - `g.X ?? 0` is equivalent to `g.X == null ? 0 : g.X`

Comment: @Caleb What do you recommend I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
reportList.Select(g => g.X ?? 0).Sum();
```

Or:

```
reportList.Select(g => g.X == null ? 0 : g.X * 100).Sum();
```